# Add constraints for a foreign key that references multipleprimary keys from different tables in SQL Plus?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

I'm a beginner learning SQL and am having trouble implementing this concept.

Suppose you create the following three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dogOwner(
 ownerNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT ownerNo_pk1 PRIMARY KEY,
 ownerName VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE catOwner(
 ownerNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT ownerNo_pk2 PRIMARY KEY,
 ownerName VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE petsAdopted(
 petNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT petNo_pk PRIMARY KEY,
 ownerNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT ownerNo_fk1 REFERENCES dogOwner(ownerNo)
                    CONSTRAINT ownerNo_fk2 REFERENCES catOwner(ownerNo)
);
```

How do you properly create constraints for the foreign key ownerNo, which references ownerNo from two other tables?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You could have 2 columns in petsAdopted: dogOwnerNo and catOwnerNo and 2 foreign keys. But the table design doesn't seem to make sense: surely a pet either is a dog or a cat (or something else) regardless of who owns it?

Here is an alternative design:

```
CREATE TABLE owner(
 ownerNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT ownerNo_pk2 PRIMARY KEY,
 ownerName VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE petsAdopted(
 petNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT petNo_pk PRIMARY KEY,
 petType VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT petTypeChk (CHECK petType in ('CAT','DOG'))
 ownerNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT ownerNo_fk REFERENCES owner(ownerNo)
);
```

Comment: These are not actual tables I am working with! I'm trying to do an assignment for class, so I didn't want to use the actual tables given in the question. I think I have it figured out now, and your response triggered my understanding.Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

This only address syntax part of your answer which You have got lot of syntax error, but this will not work, Please rethink your design.

```
 CREATE TABLE dogOwner(
 ownerNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT ownerNo_pk1 PRIMARY KEY,
 ownerName VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE catOwner(
 ownerNo VARCHAR(8),
 ownerName VARCHAR(10),
 CONSTRAINT ownerNo_pk2 PRIMARY KEY (ownerNo),
 CONSTRAINT ownerNo_fk1  FOREIGN KEY (ownerNo) REFERENCES dogOwner(ownerNo)
);

CREATE TABLE petsAdopted(
 petNo VARCHAR(8) ,
 ownerNo VARCHAR(8),
CONSTRAINT petNo_pk PRIMARY KEY (petNo),
CONSTRAINT ownerNo_fk_pet1 FOREIGN KEY (ownerNo) REFERENCES dogOwner(ownerNo),
CONSTRAINT ownerNo_fk_pet2  FOREIGN KEY (ownerNo) REFERENCES catOwner(ownerNo)
);
```

Comment: This is not going to work because `ownerno` must reference existing values. Assume you have a dogowner with `ownerno = 'one'` and a catowner with `ownerno = 'two'` then you can insert a row referencing the dogowner in `petsadopted` because it would violate the FK to `catowner`

Comment: Got it, what you saying design is wrong, my answer only address on syntax part of it but not address the conceptual part of it , i will edit and mention this in my answer.